# Who is the intended audience of Python's PEP7, and is it still considered valid?

Tags: python, c, python-c-extension

I recently stumbled upon [PEP7](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0007/) (Python's style guide for C code), and it has left me a bit confused.

Most of PEP7 makes sense for a general-purpose style guide (rules about whitespace, line length, indentation, etc.), but the section [Naming Conventions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0007/#naming-conventions) seems very specific to the CPython codebase itself:

> - Use a `Py` prefix for public functions; never for static functions. The `Py_` prefix is reserved for global service routines like `Py_FatalError`; specific groups of routines (e.g. specific object type APIs) use a longer prefix, e.g. `PyString_` for string functions.
> - Public functions and variables use MixedCase with underscores, like this: `PyObject_GetAttr`, `Py_BuildValue`, `PyExc_TypeError`.
> - Occasionally an "internal" function has to be visible to the loader; we use the `_Py` prefix for this, e.g.: `_PyObject_Dump`.
> - Macros should have a MixedCase prefix and then use upper case, for example: `PyString_AS_STRING`, `Py_PRINT_RAW`.

These guidelines would make total sense if I were modifying CPython itself, but as a C-extension author I would rather avoid naming my functions in such a way that they could be mistaken as being from the CPython API.

Additionally, there are the following two points from the [C Dialect](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0007/#c-dialect) section:

> - Use ANSI/ISO standard C (the 1989 version of the standard). This means (amongst many other things) that all declarations must be at the top of a block (not necessarily at the top of function).
> - No compiler warnings with major compilers (gcc, VC++, a few others).

The direction to use C89 probably made sense in 2001 when PEP7 was written. However, I have found that if I try to compile a C-extension with the `-std=c89 -pedantic-errors` flags, the compilation fails because of issues coming from the `Python.h` header (such as use of `long long` type, comparing signed and unsigned integers, or creating a variable as part of the init step of a for loop).  This makes me wonder how strictly this PEP is followed, and if I should bother making my C-extensions comply with C89, or just compile without warnings/errors across most compilers.

---

Is the intended audience of [PEP7](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0007/) contributors to the CPython codebase or to C-extension writers in general?  In either case, is the PEP still considered valid (like [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)) or is it mostly ignored at this point?

Comment: Note that MSVC *still* doesn't support declarations that aren't at the top of a block, so that advice is still current.

Comment: @MarkDickinson My understanding is the Python compiles with C++ on windows, so in that case wouldn't it be fine? https://docs.python.org/2/extending/windows.html

Comment: Hmm, not sure. I do know that I've encountered compiler failures for C extensions on Windows due to ignoring that rule.  It does look as though that rule might be relaxed in VS 2013, though.

Comment: Read the very first sentence of the introduction: "This document gives coding conventions for the C code **comprising the C implementation of Python.**" (emphasis mine).

Comment: @MarkDickinson I see.  I totally understand why striving for C89 is best for compatibility, especially with MSVC still floating around there. But what has me confused is that Python does not seem to follow C89 strictly, so it's not clear to me when it is OK to break compliance.

Comment: @SethMMorton: That is about **extensions**, as the URL already implies. These can be build in C or C++ on any platform. CPython itself is built (as the name says) in C. Trying to make any non-trivial project to compile identical in both, C and C++, is mutilation of both languages.

Comment: @MarkDickinson: MSVC is some rubbish non-standard compiler. It should not be used anyway. Making code compatible with that just sustains to the bad reputation C got from K&R and C90.

Comment: @Olaf  Thanks.  Since I was initially confused about what the PEP applied to, I was taking a shotgun approach with asking about both CPython and the  extension modules.